# (230v)AC-DC(12v) wall adapter flashes when connected to dc to dc buck converter

Tags: power-supply, dc, buck, ac-dc

So I used a common 230vAC to 12vDc (1AMP) wall adapter with dc jack like this[image]

and converted to 5v using a dc to dc buck converter same as based on lm2596s [image]
But the adapter LED starts blinking (normally the LED should just light up ) even if the output is not connected to anything.
**My Question: Why is it happening and what can I do to overcome this issue?**
**update 1:** I have tried using a 12vDC 20Amps SMPS and it works well.But not with the 12VDC 1Amps adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the input capacitor has a low ESR the surge current may be up to 12V/ESR.

If the supply starts up with the Buck connected then a slow start might work with a suitable ICL, Inrush Current Limiter.

Ic = C dV/dt  Choose 1A or get a [variety](https://www.digikey.ca/products/en/circuit-protection/inrush-current-limiters-icl/151?k=icl%201A&k=&pkeyword=icl%201A&sv=0&pv2182=u12%20Ohms&pv2182=u16%20Ohms&pv2182=u20%20Ohms&pv2182=u22%20Ohms&pv2182=u30%20Ohms&pv2182=u33%20Ohms&pv2182=u50%20Ohms&pv2182=u60%20Ohms&sf=0&FV=ffe00097%2Cmu1A%7C679&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25) of values with a 12~22  Ohm minimum R @ 25°C

TI's standard design shows 27uF 40 mOhm for Cin.  Thus if the 12V output is cycling On and OFF with the Buck regulator connected, 12V/40mOhm = 300A ( in theory ) but in practice limited by supply.

[image]

### Recommendation:

- Use a 1A ICL for a 1A source.
- use a DC source with a soft-start and larger surge capacity such as a 19V 65W Laptop charger.

Comment: what software did you use to create the schematic and waveform?

Comment: so @ Sunnyskyguy ,Your point is that if I add ICL I can prevent the blinking(indicating high current flow).Also can you please explain the waveform  Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: @Amrith The schematic/waveform are probably made on TI's [webench](http://www.ti.com/tools-software/design-center/webench-power-designer.html)